# Multiply each row of a matrix by another matrix

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix

Say I have the following matrix

```
B = [1 2 3;4 5 6;7 8 9;10 11 12]
```

and another matrix

```
A = [a b c;d e f;g h i]
```

How do I multiply each row of matrix B by the matrix A (without using a for loop), i.e.

```
for i = 1:4
    c(i) = B(i,:)*A*B(i,:)'
end
```

many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use:

```
c = diag(B*A*B.');
```

However, this computes a whole 4×4 matrix only to extract its diagonal, so it's not very efficient.

A more efficient way that only computes the desired values is:

```
c = sum(bsxfun(@times, permute(sum(bsxfun(@times, B, permute(A, [3 1 2])), 2), [1 3 2]), B), 2);
```

Here is a breakdown of the above code:

```
c1 = sum(bsxfun(@times, B, permute(A, [3 1 2])), 2); % B(i,:)*A
c = sum(bsxfun(@times, permute(c1, [1 3 2]), B), 2); % (B(i,:)*A)*B(i,:)'
```

The first `permute` is used so that the number of columns in **B** matches the number of columns in **A**. Following the element-wise multiplication in `bsxfun()` each row is summed up (remember, `permute` shifted the rows into the 2nd-dimension), reproducing the effect of the vector-matrix multiplication **B(i,:)** * **A** occurring in the `for` loop.

Following the first `sum`, the 2nd-dimension is a singleton dimension. So, we use the second `permute` to move the 2nd-dimension into the 3rd-dimension and produce a 2-D matrix. Now, both **c1** and **B** are the same size. Following element-wise multiplication in the second `bsxfun()` each column is summed up (remember, `permute` shifted columns back into the 2nd-dimension), reproducing the effect of **B(i,:)** * **A** * **B(i,:)'**.

Take note of a hidden advantage in this approach. Since we are using element-wise multiplication to replicate the results of matrix multiplication, order of the arguments doesn't matter in the `bsxfun()` calls. One less thing to worry about!

Or, from Matlab R2016b onwards, you can replace `bsxfun(@times,...)` by `.*`, thanks to [implicit expansion](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2016/10/24/matlab-arithmetic-expands-in-r2016b/):

```
c = sum(permute(sum(B.*permute(A, [3 1 2]), 2), [1 3 2]).*B, 2);
```

Comment: When it comes to matrix multiplication / manipulations in MATLAB, order of operations can be a huge pain. There's some hidden beauty in this approach because element-wise multiplication doesn't require you to keep track of the order. Just make sure you have the right matrices in the `bsxfun()` call and you're good to go! Great answer

Comment: @VladislavMartin Thanks! Also for the extensive edit